# App Crashes on Button Click that was supposed to send a call instantly

Tags: android-studio, button, android-intent

I have set up the button such a way that upon the click of a button it will send a call. when the button is clicked the app crashes. Please Help me debug this. Please suggest if there are alternative ways i can code a button to send a call directly upon clicking on it. I have granted permission in the settings as well.

```
package com.example.allegiant;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button dial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dial = findViewById(R.id.dial);

    }

    public void onDialButton(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tell:12345678"));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat

```
2021-03-22 21:56:33.365 7530-7530/com.example.allegiant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.allegiant, PID: 7530
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tell:12345678 }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at com.example.allegiant.MainActivity.onDialButton(MainActivity.java:34)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding READ_PHONE_STATE permission in manifest as well as ask it before click.

```
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Also surround your code inside click with try - catch having `ActivityNotFoundException`   handling

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by your second suggestion?

Comment: To make a call, an app needs READ-PHONE_STATE  runtime permission. Maybe this is the reason behind the crash.